# an interesting game

Tags: probability, random

Alice, Bob and Cindy are playing a game of a circle. Firstly, Alice starts by drawing a point around the circle. Subsequently, being aware of Alice's decision Bob makes his move. Finally, Cindy puts a point around the circle being aware of Alice's and Bob's decisions. After all players fix their positions a point X drawn around the circle randomly. The winner of the game is the one whose position is the closest to the point X.

Question: How should Bob make his choice in order to maximize the probability of winning?

Comment: When you mean closest do you mean in a particular direction, that is, clockwise or anticlockwise? Or is it Euclidean distance?

Comment: Sorry, when we draw a point around a circle, do that mean outside of the circle?

Comment: @BalakrishnanRajan, by closest I mean clockwise or anticlockwise direction

Comment: @nafhgood, I mean on the circle (neither inside or outside of it)

Comment: Please restore the original title. It' tells _nothing_ about the contents now (especially because _interesting_ is highly subjective), while the previous one contained three important details, related to the nature of the problem. Those details may help others to find for your problem and its solution if they ever have a similar one. See advices at Meta, thread [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), section [A good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144).

Answer (score 6):

No matter how distance is measured (among those possibilities mentioned in a comment), he should put it opposite to that of Alice. The notion of 'probability' only makes sense though if Cindy is using a mathematically well-defined strategy.

Let the circle circumference go from $0$ to $1$. Say wlog. that Alice chooses $0$.
Also wlog. say that Bob chooses some $a\in[0,0.5]$. Then the optimal place for Cindy is $(a+1)/2$.
The range of Bob winning is $[a/2,((a+1)/2+a)/2]$ the length of which is $(a+1)/4$ which is maximized by $a=1/2$.